# Some code lines are executing different ways according to iOS 7 and 8 in Xcode 6.1

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8

Our current Xcoce 5 project was moved to Xcode 6.
But some code lines are firing different way according to the iOS version 7 and 8 in XCode 6.

Below is the example.

There are two classes, one is AddEditClass.m and other one is AddPhoto.m class.
AddPhoto.m class in the subclass of AddEditClass.m class.

AddPhoto.m class is being used camera functionality.
So below is the cancel delegate method of camera functionality.

AddPhoto.m

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    ..Line 1 ..;

    UIViewController *presentingController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];    
    [presentingController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    ..Line 4 ..;
    ..Line 5 ..;
    ..Line 6 ..;

}
```

AddEditClass.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    ..Line 1 ..;
    ..Line 2 ..;
    ..Line 3 ..;
    ..Line 4 ..;
}
```

Abow two methods are running different ways according to the iOS 7 and 8 versions in XCode 6.1.

***iOS 7 version execution***

- exe 1 :  AddPhoto.m's ..Line 1..;
- exe 2 :  AddPhoto.m's
  UIViewController *presentingController = [[[[UIApplication
  sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
- exe 3 :  AddPhoto.m's [presentingController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
- exe 4 :  AddEditClass.m's  ..Line 1..;
- exe 5 :  AddEditClass.m's  ..Line 2..;
- exe 6 :  AddEditClass.m's  ..Line 3..;
- exe 7 :  AddEditClass.m's  ..Line 4..;
- exe 8 :  AddPhoto.m's ..Line 4..;
- exe 9 :  AddPhoto.m's ..Line 5..;
- exe 10 :  AddPhoto.m's ..Line 6..;

***iOS 8 version execution***

- exe 1 :  AddPhoto.m's ..Line 1..;
- exe 2 :  AddPhoto.m's UIViewController *presentingController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
- exe 3 :  AddPhoto.m's [presentingController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
- exe 4 :  AddPhoto.m's ..Line 4..;
- exe 5 :  AddPhoto.m's ..Line 5..;
- exe 6 :  AddPhoto.m's ..Line 6..;
- exe 7 :  AddEditClass.m's  ..Line 1..;
- exe 8 :  AddEditClass.m's  ..Line 2..;
- exe 9 :  AddEditClass.m's  ..Line 3..;
- exe 10 :  AddEditClass.m's  ..Line 4..;

So I want to fire same way as iOS 7 execution for iOS 8 also. So How can I fire code iOS 8 execution like iOS 7 execution ?

Comment: You are dismissing the image picker incorrectly. Get rid of the `presentingController` lines and call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` on `picker`. See what that does.

Comment: [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; same way it is being fired wneh i use above code line.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does the different sequence matter? Your code should not depend on that order.